# Ionic 2 app crash

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic2, base64

I am selecting images through **Cordova image picker plugin** and converting them to base64 string. After that, I **clear the temp images on android** which was generated by plugin. Everything works fine; all temporary images get removed but after that the application **crashes(not crashes natively, just go to background and reintialize when resumed again) sometimes**. Even when there is no processing or any function call after that. Is there any way I could trace why it is happening because no line of code is there to execute after cleaning those temp files.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Documentation in https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker

> If Base64 Strings are being returned, there is nothing to clean up.

May be you don't have to clean up at all.

Comment: I have used this plugin; it gives error and does not integrate with the application. Unable to build app with this plugin. Also my issue is not cleaning, I can see all file sucessfully removed but after that app crashes and I want to trace that

Comment: Well, am I talking about a different plugin?

Comment: I am converting to base64 with my methods and not plugin

Comment: Yes, I am using this plugin https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker. It doesn't have any kind of option for base64; only fileURI

Comment: Well... It looks more like it is developer's hand. The one I have provided is a fork of it anyway. Did you try running the app with 'consolelogs' flag, checking whether it outputs any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Add camera plugin to your app `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`
Then in ts file use the following code

```
  takePicture() {
    var options = {
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    };
    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.photoTaken = true;
      this.photoSelected = false;
    }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
    });
  }
```

In html use this

```
<ion-col>
  <button ion-button (click)="takePicture()">Edit</button>
</ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" />
  </ion-col>
```

this will directly give base64 image

Comment: My question is different! Also, this plugin allows only to select one image at a time.